All combinations of ascending/descending digits
We start with a list:
{3, 8, 1, 0, 5}

I want to get a sorted list of all possible numbers out of that which are in ascending order (of course excluding the ones with zero in the leading position:
0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15, 18, ..., 135, 138, 158, ..., 1358, ...

And descending order next (assume it's longer (due to the zero))
0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 30, 31, 50, 51, ..., 85310, ...


Why we need to remove 35, 38, 58 ?

We should not....that was just a few samples! Need those included

I'm not sure what your context is, but unless there is some compelling reason, I wouldn't worry about handling the 0 case specially. FromDigits can handle leading 0 and Union will deal with duplicates and do the sorting for you.
list = {3, 8, 1, 0, 5};

ascendingDigits = Union[FromDigits /@ Subsets[Sort[list]]]
(* {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15, 18, 35, 38, 58, 135, 138, 158, 358, 1358} *)

descendingDigits = Union[FromDigits /@ Subsets[ReverseSort[list]]]
(* {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 30, 31, 50, 51, 53, 80, 81, 83, 85, 310, 510, 530, 531, 810, 830, 831, 850, 851, 853, 5310, 8310, 8510, 8530, 8531, 85310} *)


The leading zero happens because Subsets always returns {} as its first item. Try adding Rest, for example with two test cases: Map[Union[FromDigits /@ Rest@Subsets[Sort[#]]]&, {{4, 2}, {4, 0}}] gives {{2, 4, 24}, {0, 4}} versus {{0, 2, 4, 24}, {0, 4}} without Rest.

list = {3, 8, 1, 0, 5};
nonzero = Complement[Sort[list], {0}];
Join[Sort@list, FromDigits /@ Subsets[nonzero, {2, Length@nonzero}]]


{0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15, 18, 35, 38, 58, 135, 138, 158, 358, 1358}


Thanks, looks great! By the way I notice Union also works in place of Join, right?

To replicate @cvgmt's output without Subsets:
Range[0, 10^Length@alist - 1] // IntegerDigits // 
     Select[ContainsOnly[alist]] // Select[OrderedQ] // 
   Select[DuplicateFreeQ] // Map[FromDigits] // Union


{0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15, 18, 35, 38, 58, 135, 138, 158, 358, 1358}


For the second part:
Range[0, 10^Length@alist - 1] // IntegerDigits // 
     Select[ContainsOnly[alist]] // Select[OrderedQ@*Reverse] // 
   Select[DuplicateFreeQ] // Map[FromDigits] // Union


{0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 30, 31, 50, 51, 53, 80, 81, 83, 85, 310, 510, 
530, 531, 810, 830, 831, 850, 851, 853, 5310, 8310, 8510, 8530, 8531,
\ 85310}



This assumes one of digits is 0 otherwise we have to use Subsets[%, {1, Infinity}] instead of Subsets@%.
Sort@{3, 8, 1, 0, 5};
Subsets@%;
Reverse /@ %;
FromDigits /@ %% // Union
FromDigits /@ %% // Union


{0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15, 18, 35, 38, 58, 135, 138, 158, 358, 1358}

{0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 30, 31, 50, 51, 53, 80, 81, 83, 85, 310, 510,
530, 531, 810, 830, 831, 850, 851, 853, 5310, 8310, 8510, 8530, 8531, 85310}

